# How to remove blur from canvas sprite

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a piece of code that creates a sprite from a piece of text.

```
var getPicture = function(message){
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var fontSize = 10;
  context.font = fontSize + "px Times New Roman";
  var measurements = context.measureText(message);
  canvas.width = measurements.width + 10;
  canvas.height = fontSize + 2;
  context.fillText(message, 0, 10);

  return canvas;
};

var getLabel = function(message){
  var texture = new THREE.Texture(getPicture(message));
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture});
  var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
  return sprite;
};
```

But unfortunately, the sprite looks like this:

[image: blurry text]

How do I get crisp text in my scene?

Comment: Try to scale up the dimensions of your canvas. You can also change the `anisotropy` of your texture, in case the plane is rotated. I would recommend you check [Signed distance fonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-bmfont-text) which give way better result with respect to texture text.

Comment: The default wrapping mode for [`Three#Texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture) is [`ClampToEdgeWrapping`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Textures) which will stretch your texture UV

Comment: What does it have to do with wrapping?

Comment: Adding `texture.anisotropy = 16` did nothing, unfortunately. What do you mean by increasing the dimensions of the canvas? When I load just the generated image, it shows the text clear and crisp in a rectangular image.

Comment: `anisotropy` will improve the result when the plane is rotated. But as you're using Sprites (which always face the camera), you don't have to bother with that, sorry.
First remember that sprites are squares. Here you're applying a "100x18" texture on a 500x500 3D Sprite, hence the blur effect. Try to create a square canvas big enough (like `canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;`) and `fillText` in the center of the canvas.

Comment: That works slightly better, but I wonder where the 500 comes from. Shouldn't I be ok using the measured text width as the square size?

Comment: Let's say your 3D sprite is 400 by 400 pixels wide on your screen. When you apply a texture on it, the texture is gonna be scaled to 400x400 no matter what's the initial size of the texture. It's always better to scale from 500x500 to 400x400 than from 100x18 to 400x400... 500px was an example.

Comment: I see, so I want to use a bigger canvas size for my text, and keep it a square...